# Need to copy file after it's creation and changing

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I need to copy a file after it's been created and changed twice.

I have no idea how to do it, except by using 3 FileSystemWachers. First one on creation and two for changing.

Is there any easier way?

Comment: One FileSystemWacher is enough. but how can we answer it other than write it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FileSystemWatcher` has [several events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you can use to listen to different types of events on the file system. There is also a [`NotifyFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which you can use to specify which event types it should monitor.

So you don't need to use three different watchers; one would suffice. You just need some form of counter to keep track of how many changes were made to the file. Here's a quick example:

```
Dictionary<string, int> changeCounter = new Dictionary<string, int>();

...

FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = @"C:\Path\To\Some\Folder";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Created += OnCreated;
watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

...

private void OnCreated(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    changeCounter.Add(e.FullPath, 0);
}
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (changeCounter.ContainsKey(e.FullPath))
    {
        changeCounter[e.FullPath]++;
        if (changeCounter[e.FullPath] == 2) 
        {
            CopyFile(e.FullPath);
        }
    }
}
```

This would only call `CopyFile` after the watcher detected a file creation event and two file change events for a single file. You may also want to modify handle deletions, too, in case you are worried about files being created once, edited, deleted, recreated, and edited—this would trigger `CopyFile` even though, technically, the file has only been edited once after it was created.